# In MATLAB (cumulative distribution function), how can I find the corresponding data point (Y) for any chosen cumulative probability?

Tags: matlab, plot, normal-distribution, cdf

In a CDF (using MATLAB) how can I find the corresponding data value (X) for any chosen cumulative distribution (Y)?  Please refer to the pasted code (I would post an image but I need a "10 reputation").  Instead of "eye-balling" the plot, how can I find the data point (X) that corresponds to the cumulative probability value of 0.2 or even 0.5, etc.?  Please advise.  Thank you.

```
X = randn(1,500);
u = mean(X);
s = std(X);
pd = makedist('Normal','mu',u,'sigma',s);
x = min(X):.1:max(X);
cdf_normal = cdf(pd,x);
plot(x,cdf_normal,'LineWidth',4)
```

Comment: Here is a pic of the image:  


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MZmqg.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what is in `makedist`, but Matlab has a powerful tool called `find` which will seek out what you need.

In your case, if I had to guess, you can do

```
x(find(cdf_normal >= 0.2,1))
```

to get your desired data point x.

Basically it searches cdf_normal for the first occurrence of the correct statement, returns the index, then displays the value if x which corresponds to that index.